# Flexible Display of Changing Tabular Info?

Tags: javascript, html, html-table, content-management-system

I have a staff page for an organization. Currently there are 33 staff members organized in a table in rows of three. Each column has their picture, name, and a link to their email, twitter, etc. They are organized in alphabetical order, so the table might (pseudo) look like this:

```
<table>
 <tr>
  <td>Jane Doe Stuff</td>
  <td>Jim Enn Stuff</td>
  <td>William Far Stuff</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>Brian Ghan Stuff</td>
  <td>Anne Hand Stuff</td>
  <td>Mary Kite Stuff</td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

The problem arises when someone leaves - e.g., if Jim Enn leaves then Far needs to move into his column and Ghan into Far's column, Hand into Ghan's column, and Kite into Hand's column. An awful lot of unnecessary work to remove a single employee.

Similarly, if an individual is added to the table (say James Frat) one has to shift Ghan, Hand, and Kite all down one column to make room for Frat.

One of the big things I'm working on is replacing the CMS the organization currently uses, which is proprietary and limited. Normally I'd keep the data in a database, sort and dynamically insert the data info appropriate columns...but I don't have access to the database back-end.

I do have access to the HTML - though the editor occasionally garbles my input (of course, when I put in a line break I meant for you to convert it to a paragraph)

It provides access to the head of the document as well, which is nice. Theoretically I can use JavaScript, but this also may get mucked up. Looking for thoughts on how I can accomplish this within my current constraints?

Comment: It is REALLY weird to present data in mixed columns like that. If you organize the actual table in rows, you can display it however you like using formatting with CSS and javascript... but if the data isn't properly organized, formatting it becomes really difficult.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of a `table`, you should be using `div`s and floating them.  This way if one div gets removed, the others will fill in.